# Biblatex-Chicago notes and author-date formats

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I would like to use the package biblatex-chicago in my document, but with the following options:

- use the style "notes" for the bibliography
- use the style "author-date" for the citations

in order to have the following result

[image]

[image]

I kept looking but couldn't find a way to get this result.

If I use the style 'notes', it is not possible to have citations in the form of (Author,year), I can either have the author alone, or the year or the whole reference, or a number with the reference in footnotes. But then if I use the style 'author-date', my bibliography looks different with the format "Author, Year, Title" instead of "Author, Title, Year"

It seems that it is possible to have different styles for bibliography and citations with biblatex (using bibstyle and citestyle), but not with biblatex-chicago.
Is there another way?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This citation/bibliography set-up is slightly confusing in that it may be harder to match citation labels to bibliography entries. A reader will only have the author(s) and year of a work to go on when she consults the bibliography. But in a "`notes`" bibliography the year is not in the prominent place at the beginning of the entry, instead it comes near the end, especially in entries with several lines one can get lost trying to find the year. With the "`authordate`" bibliography style the year also comes at the beginning and it is much easier to match citation labels to bibliography entries.

Anyway, the styles of the `biblatex-chicago` bundle are not supposed to be mixed and matches in this way. There are far too many interdependencies between the bibliography style (`.bbx` file) and citation style (`.cbx` file), on the other hand there are incompatibilities between the bibliography and citation styles of different substyles, so there is almost no hope of loading and then overwriting a style. In only see two options to resolve this (1) undefine all problematic macros before loading the new style or (2) copy only the relevant bits of both styles into a new style. Both options are doable, but extremely tedious due to the fact that `biblatex-chicago`'s style files weigh in at several thousand lines of code each.

If you insist on this slightly confusing mix of styles, I recommend you look at [`windycity`](https://ctan.org/pkg/windycity). `windycity` is a more recent implementation of Chicago Style and its structure gives easier access to the output you want. Note that while the general output of `biblatex-chicago` and `windycity` is quite similar, there will be small (and maybe even larger) differences between two.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=windycity, ,autocite=inline]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (Worman 2002)//Sigfridsson, Emma, and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19, no. 4 (1998): 377–395. 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//Worman, Nancy. The Cast of Character: Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002.]